# Watson Unity SDK suddenly stopped working

Tags: ibm-watson

Watson Unity speech recognition has suddenly stopped working. It keeps logging an error:

```
[03/05/2019 17:39:37][SpeechToText.OnListenMessage()][ERROR] Error: <2019-03-05 17:39:37,542 api/src/rapi_common.cc:127>    RD_ERROR    RAPI: "RReco" -> "settings" -> "nbest_size" -> Integer 0 is lower than 1.
```

This is from the Speech Sandbox example streaming scene, which was working fine until now. Has something changed about the service?

Answer (score 1):

apparently there is some bug in the service, but this is a quick fix for it from the Watson developer community -slack workspace.
After creating the credentials and instantiating the service, set MaxAlternatives to 1

```
_service = new SpeechToText(credentials);
_service.MaxAlternatives = 1; //add this line
```

this fixes the problem, at least for now. Also make sure that MaxAlternatives doesn't get changed back to 0 later in the script.

Comment: Additionally there was a bug where the service sends a `1` for word confidence and an exception is thrown trying to cast it into a double. [This PR](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/pull/528) addresses that.